# Using Rack::Session::Pool with Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm exploring Sinatra and I want to use sessions but I don't want them to be stored in a Cookie, I found Rack::Session::Pool which works very well.

Now I want sessions to expire after a certain duration but I don't understand how to instanciate the Rack::Session::Pool and them use it in Sinatra.

Any Clue ?

Comment: But, doesn't [`Rack::Session::Pool`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Pool.html) use cookies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your rackup file:

```
%w(rubygems rack sinatra).each { |dependency| require dependency }
disable :run

require 'myapp'

sessioned = Rack::Session::Pool.new(
  Sinatra::Application,
  :domain       => 'example.com',
  :expire_after => 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 # expire after 1 year
)
run sessioned
```

To launch run `rackup app.ru`, or use Passenger, etc.  This ought to wrap your application in the session pool and enable its functionality.  I don't entirely know why it doesn't need *use* like most other middleware.

Understand that I haven't tested this at all, I haven't had something that needed session pools yet.  I wrote this from the [documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Session/Pool.html) for Rack::Session::Pool, which had an example at the top of the page.  So, I can't tell you exactly how to use it either.

Answer (score 10):

Sinatra is quite powerful, the trick from The Wicked Flea didn't work but this did :

```
use Rack::Session::Pool, :domain => 'example.com', :expire_after => 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
```

Thanks !